# Append between two html tags in postgres table

Tags: html, postgresql, sql-update

Postgres table with name *postgrestable*:

```
ID    NAME    HTML
1     FRONT   <map> 
              <entry> test </entry>
              </map>
```

How can i create a update query that appends a new `<entry></entry>` between the `<map>` tags. The table should be updated to this form:

```
ID    NAME    HTML
1     FRONT   <map> 
              <entry> test </entry>
              <entry> secondentry </entry>
              </map>
```

I have tried with REGEXP_REPLACE between tags, but that deletes all entries between `<map>` tags and inserts the entry you updated. Any other idea?

Comment: Your map tag is not closed at the end. Is this right?

Comment: Yes it was a typo, is edited now.

Answer (score 1):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=cb0b104b76a4e2ef2150fc70c2910901)

```
SELECT 
     regexp_replace(xml, match, match || '<entry>secondentry</entry>')
FROM (
    SELECT
        xml,
        (regexp_matches(xml,'^<map>(.*)</map>$'))[1] as match
    FROM (
        SELECT '<map><entry>test</entry></map>' as xml
    ) s
) s
```

Using your way with `regexp_replace`:

1. `regexp_matches` gives the whole content of `<map>`
2. `regexp_replace` replaces the whole content of `<map>` with its content AND the new one.

---

**Edit**: The whole UPDATE would look like:

```
UPDATE postgrestable
SET html =
(
    SELECT 
        regexp_replace(xml, match, match || '<entry>secondentry</entry>')
    FROM (
        SELECT
            xml,
            (regexp_matches(xml,'^<map>(.*)</map>$'))[1] as match
        FROM (
            SELECT '<map><entry>test</entry></map>' as xml
        ) s
    ) s
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort. It is not meant to be done only by regexp_replace. As i am not experienced with postgres, how can the update query look like with this statement, as i could not make it use.

Comment: Updated fiddle and added the UPDATE code. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I was trying to make it use but unfortunately could not, receive a error : failed to find conversion function from unknown to text. 
I tried a way now, as following : 
`update postgrestable set html = regexp_replace(html,'</map>', '<entry>secondentry</entry>\1') where id=1;  ` and worked!!!  Thank you for the ffort once more!